# problem in texturing

Tags: textures, directx11, rendertexture

[image]

[image]

the first picture is the texture I'm using.
and the second is result. problem!

the model file it self is no problem. I think the mode is problem.

I saw uv coordinates is more than 1.

what kind of sampler state I should use?

I used default sampler state that is wrap mode for u,v,w.

Comment: Can you show us the UV unwrap being used on the model? Also, I see you've tagged this question "rendertexture" — are you using a RenderTexture here (ie. a texture that's being generated at runtime as the output of another rendering process)? If so, you should include details of how you're dynamically populating the texture.

Comment: Oh.. I thought it was about texturing. Sorry.

Comment: what.. I'm confused... default is clamp mode... thanks my man it's solved

Answer (score 1):

I searched MSDN AND I saw default sampler is wrap. But! that was XNA not dx11
if you don't setting your sampler state it's fine dx11 will set default sampler state.

check here what is default state
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476207(v=vs.85).aspx
thank you DMGregory. I just find this out when I'm trying to fill D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC structure